# AF-XDP: Load kernel program only once but distribute access to xsks-map to multiple processes

Tags: c, linux, bpf, xdp-bpf

As far as I understand there can only be one AF-XDP kernel program per network interface. I want to distribute packet processing from multiple multicast-addresses from a single network interface to several processes. I have written a "loader"-program which creates the processes (works fine so far).

My problem now is to load the kernel program only once via `load_bpf_and_xdp_attach` in the loader-program but to distribute access to the xsks-map to multiple processes.

`load_bpf_and_xdp_attach` returns a pointer to a `struct bpf_object*`. This pointer is then needed by `bpf_object__find_map_by_name` to gain access to the `bpf_map` file descriptor.

My idea was to write the content of `bpf_object` into shared memory thus distributing it to the processes. But unfortunately, the struct `bpf_object` is defined in `libbpf.c`. Because of this I am not able to do this:

```
void insert_bpf_obj_into_shrd_mem(int shmid, struct bpf_object *bpf_obj) {

    uint8_t *shm_data = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(shm_data == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obtain `shared memory` with id %d: %s\n", shmid, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(shm_data, bpf_obj, sizeof(struct bpf_object));
    shmdt(shm_data);
}
```

This to me looks like, `libbpf` doesn't want anyone to know about `bpf_object`.

Any ideas how I can accomplish my initial idea?

In case every process loads its own version of the kernel program, I end up with `(amount of processes)`-xsks maps and I don't think this is sensible.

Edit: I know there is a way to reuse maps but...seems kind of intricate

Comment: The internals of `struct bpf_object` are intentionally kept hidden to the application calling libbpf indeed. Reusing maps sound like the good approach here, I gave a few pointers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227624/3716552).

Comment: @Qeole I just noticed that it doesn't matter whether I load the map! I just do `load_bpf_and_xdp_attach(cfg);` in the distributor and don't load anything in the user-programs processes. I don't understand how this works but somehow the sockets now where to find the xsks-map?

Comment: Linking to [the answer on the multi-process setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658171/3716552)