# AF-XDP: Implement Shared Umem sockets

Tags: c, linux, xdp-bpf

I want to implement XDP_SHARED_UMEM: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/af_xdp.html#xdp-shared-umem-bind-flag

The `libbpf` library function `xsk_socket__create` (https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/xsk.c) checks the `xsk_umem->refcount` value. In case it is greater than 1, the `XDP_SHARED_UMEM` option of a `struct sockaddr_xdp` is set.

So as far as I understand correctly, I "just" need to pass the original umem struct of the socket I want to share the umem with and the rest is done by `libbpf`.

The way I tried to do it was to let the first process copy its `umem`-struct into a shared-memory area where the second process could load it from. But because `struct xsk_umem` is defined in `xsk.c` it is hidden from the user and I am not able to do something like this:

`memcpy(shdm_ptr, umem, sizeof(struct xsk_umem))`

I don't know how they expect someone to use the shared umem feature?

Comment: Would the example available in [kernel samples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c?h=v5.5#n279) be helpful here?

Comment: As far as I understand, `umem->buffer` is just the pointer to the memory area but I don't get the other variables of `struct xsk_umem` such as `fd` or `refcount` which are necessary for `xsk_socket__create` to set `XDP_SHARED_UMEM` accordingly. I am probably wrong but I don't see how this function helps me

Comment: Right, sorry. I don't know then :/. Could be that libbpf just doesn't have those helpers yet.

Comment: I see there's `xsk_umem__fd()` in libbpf, could you use it to get the file descriptor and pass it to other processes? (I have not tried, no idea if this is supposed to work)

Comment: I could do that but again `xsk_socket__create` expects a `struct xsk_umem *umem`. In order to be able to pass the `fd` directly to `xsk_socket__create` I have to change the library (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was discussed [on the xdp-newbies](https://marc.info/?t=158399976300001&r=1&w=2) mailing list. Reporting here for the record.

It is not recommended to go with a multi-process setup as you are trying to do. Björn says:

> Note that if you'd like to
>   do a multi-**process** setup with shared umem, you: need to have a
>   control process that manages the fill/completion rings, and
>   synchronize between the processes, OR re-mmap the fill/completetion
>   ring from the socket owning the umem in multiple processes **and**
>   synchronize the access to them. Neither is pleasant.
>
> Honestly, not a setup I'd recommend.

And he adds:

> Just for completeness; To setup shared umem:
>
> 1. create socket 0 and register the umem to this.
> 2. mmap the fr/cr using socket 0
> 3. create socket 1, 2, n and refer to socket 0 for the umem.
>
> So, in a multiprocess solution step 3 would be done in separate
>   processes, and step 2 depending on your application. You'd need to
>   pass socket 0 to the other processes **and** share the umem memory from
>   the process where socket 0 was created. This is pretty much a threaded
>   solution, given all the shared state.
>
> I advice not taking this path.

(Credits to Björn.)