# How to share BPF maps between two kernel space BPF programs?

Tags: kernel, bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

Before I present my matter; I have read this [Map sharing between different ebpf program types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455605/map-sharing-between-different-ebpf-program-types)
previously asked question which does not seem to answer my question.

Now, what I am doing is, I have two BPF programs, one for XDP and other for TC (No Userspace program). I have created the map in TC program and pinned it to global namespace

```
struct bpf_elf_map cnt_map __section("maps") = {
    .type           = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .size_key       = sizeof(uint32_t),
    .size_value     = sizeof(uint32_t),
    .pinning        = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,
    .max_elem       = 2,
};
```

Now, I want to access the same map in my XDP code. The document says that the pinned object can be obtained using `BPF_OBJ_GET`, but what all I could find is the userspace version of this.

So, I need to know, how can two kernel space BPF programs can share a map? If it's possible with `BPF_OBJ_GET` to get the pinned object (in my case it's a map), then how? Or is there any other way of doing it?

A code example of how to access the pinned object in other kernel space BPF program is really appreciated since I am new to XDP/BPF or tc/BPF.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that the map is truly pinned? Do you see it in `/sys/fs/bpf/` somewhere?

Comment: Solved offline - issues were wrong command lines for compiling and loading the program.

Comment: The second part still remains....That is how to retrieve the file descriptor (in another kernel space bpf program) of the pinned object (from one kernel space bpf program).

Comment: If the definition and name of the map are the same for your XDP program than for your TC program, I think `ip link` is able to handle this for you and to reuse the existing map, but I'm not 100% sure. If it's not, you can alternatively load and attach your XDP program with `bpftool`, which does support reusing the map (`bpftool prog load ... map name <foo> pinned /sys/fs/bpf/foo ...`, then `bpftool net attach ...`). See [doc](https://www.mankier.com/package/bpftool).